# Enrollment process

Tags: developer-program

Enrolled in Apple developer program as a company but didn't receive mail titled "Request for enrollment documents". I tried emailing the Apple support team, got an automatic mail reply. What should I do now?

Comment: How long have you waited? The follow up e-mail could take days or weeks depending on your region.

Answer (score 1):

## Contact Apple

You should [contact Apple's iTunes Connect team](http://www.apple.com/itunes/go/itunesconnect/contactus/) and ask this question directly. Ultimately, only Apple can help.